# Ajax error on my JSON calls

Tags: fullcalendar

I just upgraded to fullcalendar 1.5.1 and updated jQuery to 1.5.2 ...

Here is my code:

```
$('#calendar_container').fullCalendar({
eventSources: [
               {
                   url: '/myapp/calendar/TestJSON.jsp',
                   type : 'POST',
                   error: function() {
            alert('there was an error while fetching events!');
        }
               } 
           ]
)}
```

Anyway my JSON feeds seem to have broken, jQuery is getting some sort of ajax error.  With Firebug I see that the call being made is: 
http://localhost:8080/myapp/calendar/TestJSON.jsp?callback=jQuery1520173438877011995_1303227625166

The error alert pops up and if I examine Firebug I see an 'ajaxError'.  Now the JSON is coming through (I can see it in the Firebug response).  The statusText is 'parsererror'.

I have already validated the JSON with JSONLint.  I have even tried 'hard coding' the JSON. The callback parameter had me worried so I added jsonp: false to the event source but while I was able to eliminate the callback parameter the error persisted.  I also tried changing the type to gET instead of POST, but to no avail.

Here is the hardcoded JSON from TestJSON.jsp:

```
[{"id":111,"title":"Event1","start":"2011-04-10"},{"id":222,"title":"Event2","start":"2011-04-20","end":"2011-04-22"}]
```

**Update**

I figured it out, it was a plugin conflict between jQuery 1.5.2 with jquery validation, but there is a fix here:
https://github.com/jaubourg/jquery-validation/raw/master/jquery.validate.min.js

Comment: The JSON itself looks valid: http://www.paulisageek.com/json_validator (uses JQuery), http://www.jsonlint.com , http://www.jsonformatter.curiousconcept.com ; Have you tried using some FF plugin/tool to view the header and ensure that is what is getting returned to JQuery?